# Unable to connect after ChrootDirectory within sshd_config

Tags: chroot, sshd

After adding the following to my sshd_config file...

```
Match user myuser
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/html
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I am unable to connect using the user 'myuser'

'myuser' has read and write access to  /var/www/html (in fact it is the owner) and that directory is set as its home directory.

If I remove these lines I can connect,  but I have access to folders below this (which I don't want)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here, because you are in a chroot enviroment (in your case is `/var/www/html`), therefore there is no things like `/bin/bash` under your file system, which really means `/var/www/html/bin/bash` because your `/` is now `/var/www/html`.

For using ssh chroot, you must copy some tools, library to your chroot enviroment, creating some devices like `/dev/null`, `/dev/tty`... It's very complicated tasks.

Fortunately, this [script](http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/make_chroot_jail.sh.html) can do those tasks for us.

Comment: Thankyou.  I will think about running that script (my server is centos which isn't on the list of distros mentioned in the script, but it might work)

As it seems to be getting a bit complicated, is there a more straightforward way to provide file transfer capabilities to the html directory other than plain ftp (which is advised against)

Comment: If you only use sftp, I think your setup is good. You can refer to this link: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/